# What is the difference between MUST and SHOULD in an Elasticsearch bool query?

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the difference between `must` and `should` in a bool query in Elasticsearch?

If I **ONLY** want results that contain my terms, should I then use `must` ?

For example, I have a query that should only contain certain values, and should also have no results that has a date/timestamp lower than today's `(time/date - NOW)`. Also, can I use multiple filters inside a `must` query like the following code?

```
"filtered": {
"filter": {
"bool" : {
        "must" : {
            "term" : { "type" : 1 }
            "term" : { "totals" : 14 }
            "term" : { "groupId" : 3 }
            "range" : {
                "expires" : {
                    "gte": "now"
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: Don't know why they just can't make it commonly used linq/lambda expression style, but instead introducing so much complexities.

Answer (score 464, accepted):

**must** means: The clause (query) must appear in matching documents. These clauses must match, like logical **AND**.

**should** means: At least one of these clauses must match, like logical **OR**.

Basically they are used like logical operators AND and OR. See [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20150924080105/https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_most_important_queries_and_filters.html#_bool_filter).

Now in a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html):

**must** means: Clauses that *must* match for the document to be included.

**should** means: If these clauses match, they increase the `_score`; otherwise, they have no effect. They are simply used to refine the relevance score for each document.

---

Yes you can use multiple filters inside `must`.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but how about `must` for categories, or pricing, and `should` for attributes, like size and colour. Now, if size L and XL are selected, it's a should between those two, but if colour green is also selected, it has to be a must have for (sizes L OR XL) AND (colour green). Is that possible?

Comment: I believe in that case _filters_ might be a better approach for attributes.  They're geared towards exact matches and not relevance based searches.  See [queries and filters](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_queries_and_filters.html) in the docs for more info.

Comment: I think you need to have `minimum_number_should_match = 1` in order to enforce the idea that "at least one of these clauses must match".

Comment: Good answer! I just want to share a part of the documentation that was very helpful for me to understand this. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_most_important_queries_and_filters.html#_bool_query

Comment: "must means: Clauses that must match for the document to be included."... I think that there is an exception for this statement. when using with multi-match query "operator" : "and" should be added. otherwise it also matches at least one like or.

Comment: My confusion was `must` and `filter`, and I found this: "`filter` Clauses that `must` match, but are **run in non-scoring**, filtering mode. These clauses do not contribute to the score, instead they simply include/exclude documents based on their criteria."
**New documentation**: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-queries-together.html

Comment: JimK - or no must clause. When there is no must clause, the minimum_number_should_match is implied.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a `bool` query with a `should` **inside** a `must` (query: { bool: { must: { query: [], should: [] } } }) assumes a different meaning, since in this scenario the `should` can influence in the number of total documents matched, correct?

Comment: Just noticed something. In a bool query if you use a `should` clause with an empty `must` clause, the `should` clause acts like a `must` clause. Just an observation

Answer (score 28):

Since this is a popular question, I would like to add that in Elasticsearch version 2 things changed a bit.

Instead of `filtered` query, one should use `bool` query in the top level.

If you don't care about the score of `must` parts, then put those parts into `filter` key. No scoring means faster search. Also, Elasticsearch will automatically figure out, whether to cache them, etc. `must_not` is equally valid for caching.

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Also, mind that `"gte": "now"` cannot be cached, because of millisecond granularity. Use two ranges in a `must` clause: one with `now/1h` and another with `now` so that the first can be cached for a while and the second for precise filtering accelerated on a smaller result set.

Answer (score 27):

As said in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/query-dsl-bool-query.html):

> Must: The clause (query) must appear in matching documents.
>
> Should: The clause (query) should appear in the matching document. In a boolean query with no must clauses, one or more should clauses must match a document. The minimum number of should clauses to match can be set using the minimum_should_match parameter.

In other words, results will have to be matched by **all** the queries present in the *must* clause ( or match **at least one** of the *should* clauses if there is no *must* clause.

Since you want your results to satisfy all the queries, you should use *must*.

---

You can indeed use filters inside a boolean query.

Comment: I think you mean "you must use must" rather than "you should use must" ;-)

Comment: i wish it were called `any` and NOT `should` :( 
Would be less ambiguous