# elasticsearch: whats the difference between "should" with two match cases and pipe char

Tags: elasticsearch

folks.

I'm new to elastic search and I have the following two search queries, which seems to do the same. But for accuracy I would like to know, if they are REALLY doing the same things:

Query 1:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [{
            "match": {
                "Adresse.values.street": "Muhstraße"
            }},
            {
            "match": {
                "Adresse.values.street": "Muhstrasse"
            }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Query 2:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "match": {
                "Adresse.values.street": "Muhstraße|Muhstrasse"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768277/elasticsearch-difference-between-must-and-should-bool-query is sufficient to understand the differenence, especially from a scoring standpoint.

Comment: Thanks, but what more chars may I use to search? In my example I used pipe char "|", but are there any other chars I can use? Such as "?" or "*" ???