# Questions about joint query？

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, booleanquery

Use Elasticsearch to search "
productID of a or (productID of  b and price of c)
"  with devp of kibana
This is my code: （what is right?）

```
 GET my_store/products/_search
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "should":[
                {
                    "match":{
                        "productId":a
                    }},
                    {"match":{
                        "productId":b
                    }
                }
                ],
            "must":{
                "match":{
                    "price":c
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help me quickly！

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @yx yao can you add some sample data against which you are running your search query ?

Comment: @yx yao did you get a chance to go through my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You want `productID of a or (productID of b and price of c)`. It sounds like

`productId=a OR (productId=b AND price=C)`

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {"productID": "a"}
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {"match": {"productID": "b"}},
                            {"match": {"price": "c"}}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You consider the below

`OR = should`
`AND = must`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned anything about the data that you have taken, I have indexed the following data:

**Sample Index Data**

```
{
   "productId":"a",
   "price": 100
}
{
   "productId":"b",
   "price": 200
}
{
   "productId":"c",
   "price": 300
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {"productId": "a"}
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {"match": {"productId": "b"}},
                            {"match": {"price": 700}}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "foo10",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.9808292,
            "_source": {
               "productId": "a",
               "price": 100
            }
         }
      ]
```

**Here, since no data match with "productId": "b" and "price": 700`, in the Search result only the data with "productId": "a" is shown.**

**You can simply consider `Must` to be equivalent to logical AND and `should` as logical OR**

Refer this to know about [Elasticsearch difference between MUST and SHOULD bool query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768277/elasticsearch-difference-between-must-and-should-bool-query#:%7E:text=must%20means%3A%20Clauses%20that%20must,use%20multiple%20filters%20inside%20must%20.) and to get detailed explanation about Boolean Query refer this official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Comment: How is it really different from the above answer? apart from sample data.

Comment: @Gibbs I also got the same search query as you got, but in my answer, I also added some sample data and some links that will hopefully make the issue more clear