# How to write ElasticSearch query with AND condition

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to write an elastic search query for searching the data with two.conditions something as below

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "trackingId": "track4324234234244",
      "log_message": "downstream request-response"
    }
  }
}
```

The above query wont work because [match] query doesn't support multiple fields. Is there a way I can achieve this.

Comment: its been a long time, did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you and if it's helpful, please don't forget to upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), where a `must` clause can be used.

**`must` means: The clause (query) must appear in matching documents. These clauses must match, like logical AND.**

To know about the difference between must and should refer to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768277/elasticsearch-difference-between-must-and-should-bool-query)

**Adding Working example with sample docs and search query**

**Index Sample Data:**

```
{
    "trackingId":"track4324234234244",
    "log_message":"downstream request-response"
}
{
    "trackingId":"track4324234234244",
    "log_message":"downstream"
}
{
    "trackingId":"tracks4324234234244",
    "log_message":"downstream request-response"
}
```

**Search query:**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "trackingId": "track4324234234244"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "log_message": {
              "query": "downstream request-response",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
        {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.8570712,
            "_source": {
                "trackingId": "track4324234234244",
                "log_message": "downstream request-response"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from [`Bool`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), you can also make use of [`simple query string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html) as mentioned below:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "fields": ["trackingId", "log_message"],
      "query": "track4324234234244 downstream request-response",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}
```

Note how I've just added all the terms and made use of `default_operator: AND` so that it returns only documents having all the terms present in the fields.

There is also [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) however I would recommend using the above one as `query_string` works in strict fashion meaning, it would throw errors if the query string has any syntax errors while `simple_query_string` does not.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["trackingId", "log_message"],
      "query": "(track4324234234244) AND (downstream request-response)",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}
```

So as to when to use `simple_query_string`, mostly only if you would want to expose the query string or terms to end user, at that point which this would be useful.

Hope that helps!