# bool query - must and should on same level, what does it means?

Tags: elasticsearch

What does bool query with `must` and `should` on same level means ?

I saw the query bellow:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        
     "must": 
        [{
          "match": {
            "content": {
              "reporter": "Ricky"             
            }
          }
        }], 
        
      "should": 
      [{
          "match": {
            "header": {
              "query": "nature"
            }
          }
        }]
      
    }
  }
}
```

- According to [Improving search relevance with boolean queries](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-improve-elasticsearch-search-relevance-with-boolean-queries) `must` means `and`, `should` means `or`
- In the query above `must` and `should` ("and" and "or") are on the same level.

1. So what does this bool query mean ?
2. Does `should` contributes here to the final score (if `must` query dosn't take any place) ?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/28768277/6064933

Answer (score 3, accepted):

must + should is only about search relevance improvement and not just and + or

1. the above query means: find me all document whose `content` field contains "ricky" and give a little boost to those documents also having "nature" in their `header` field.
2. The query in `must` **MUST be met**, i.e. if no document contain "ricky" in their `content` field, there won't be any match in the result set.

Comment: If "should" is only used in these types of queries for boosting the score only, how can one achieve something simple like `(A & B) | C` using these? let's say its number ranges so `(x>=4 & x <=6) | x=2` - which query can give you the potential result set of `2,4,5,6`? `must=A,B` and `should=C` won't work.

Comment: @Corel please feel free to start a new thread with your question

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76843879/how-to-write-a-bool-query-of-a-b-c-condition-in-elasticsearch