# Elasticsearch additional 'should' clause enforcing empty results

Tags: elasticsearch, information-retrieval

I have an Elasticsearch index for the Wikipedia corpus with documents of four types (`paragraph`, `infobox`, `list`, `and table`). Each document has the following fields: `page_title`, `section_path`, and `document_text`.

I'm querying this corpus with a question, `"what country is Narora located in?"` scoped within a single page (`"List of nuclear power stations"`) and document type (`"table"`) as the following, which should return the table documents found in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclear_power_stations) Wikipedia page.

```json
{
    "size": 100,
    "_source": [
        "id",
        "document_text",
        "section_path",
        "page_title",
    ],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "document_text": "what country is Narora located in?"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "section_path": "what country is Narora located in?"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "page_title": "what country is Narora located in?"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "page_title": "List of nuclear power stations"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "paragraph_type": "table"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This query returns empty results. When I remove one of the two `should` clauses, either `section_path` or `page_title`, I get multiple table documents as a result, including the "In service" one [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclear_power_stations), which has a mention of Narora in its `document_text` field.

Now, granted that the page_title ("List of nuclear power stations") and section_path ("In service", "Under construction" ...) don't overlap with the question. But I'm surprised by this behavior as the `should` clause is only supposed to affect the scoring, and not what matches ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768277/elasticsearch-difference-between-must-and-should-bool-query)). So adding a `should` clause shouldn't cause Elasticsearch to return an empty result.

Any thoughts on what could be going on here? Is there any way to force Elasticsearch to ignore the `should` clause/s if there's no match and still return ALL the documents that match the rest of the `must` criteria?

Comment: What is the version of Elasticsearch?

Comment: The version is `7.10.2`.

Comment: Could you try to use `minimum_should_match: 0` ?

Comment: The document you shared in StackOverflow is so old, from 2015, and also Elastic did some changes in that version related to minimum_should_match feature silently.

Comment: I could not try that version but I think the problem related with default value of `minimum_should_match`

Comment: Thanks, I did try that but it had no effect. While trying to figure out why it didn't have an effect, I found [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/52735) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html) which say that value = 0 is just ignored (granted though that the doc isn't for the same version).

Comment: Also, there is another question [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/when-does-minimum-should-match-change-default-value/286234) related to the same topic.

Comment: I think there was something broken and they changed the mentality of this field.

Comment: Maybe, we can try to restructure the query. Shortly, we are trying to ignore all shoulds for filtering the data, but also, we want to get some extra scores if these shoulds match, right?

Comment: Thanks hkulekci, for sharing the link! I'm not able to find a solution from it, but it's certainly helpful to know. ... Yes, what you describe is what I want. Can you suggest how to restructure the query?